# What IT form to use in India?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india

In Previous Year 14-15, Assessment year 15-16 I have

- income from salary
- income from two house properties
- income from Capital Gains
- Income from other sources
- income/profit from business

What form should I use to file my e return?

Answer (score 1):

As you have income from Business / Profession, you would need to use form [ITR4S](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/#main)